# PhoneGap 3.0.0 - Read locally stored HTML file into the local Safari browser for display purposes on IOS

Tags: html, ios6, cordova, mobile-safari, readfile

Good day

I am reading HTML files from an external server via JQuery AJAX call, and storing them on a local IOS 6.0 device with FileWriter. I then read the locally stored files with FileReader and I successfully get the text. What I want to achieve from here, is to take the HTML content from the locally stored file (retrieved via FileReader), and push it into the local Safari Browser on the phone for displaying the HTML page (current target market is iPhone 5). Below is some code. Any ideas how to achieve this? I have tried window.open after installing the InAppBrowser plugin (which I do not really want to use because I want to use Safari) and also returning the text in the onloadend event... document.write is also not ideal as I want to open the file in a new window/tab so that it can be closed to direct the user back to the app when done. I am also not sure if I should read as Binary or Text (assuming TEXT would be the right option because it is not a media file)

Please note that I am new to PhoneGap so my methods used may not reflect Best Practice...

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady () {
    var fileName = 'some_file.html';
    readerObject.setFileName(fileName);
    //Instantiate reader on the file
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        readerObject.gotFS, readerObject.fail);
}

// Create reader
var readerObject = {
    // Sets the file name to read from
    setFileName : function(fileName) {
        readerObject.fileName = fileName;
    },
    // Gets the file name to read from
    getFileName : function() {
        return readerObject.fileName;
    },
    // Capture the file system
    gotFS : function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(readerObject.getFileName(), null,
            readerObject.gotFileEntry, readerObject.fail);
    },
    gotFileEntry : function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(readerObject.readData, readerObject.fail);
    },
    **readData : function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            //Return text for streaming into the browser (NOT WORKING)
            //return evt.target.result;
            //Capture file path
            var filePath = file.fullPath+"/"+file.name;
            //Open file in new window (NOT WORKING)
            //window.open(filePath, '_blank', 'location=yes');
            window.open("file:///"+filePath, '_blank', 'location=yes');
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
        //reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
   },**
   fail : function(error) {
       alert(error.code);
   }
```

}

Comment: Supposedly `window.open(url, '_system')` should open in the system browser, but I can't get it to work with local files, only with external http URLs.

Comment: You may want to try ```toURL()``` instead of ```fullPath``` (I think things where changed lately). As for opening the link in Safari (meaning outside of your app), I don't know if it's possible without using a plugin (not sure if InAppBrowser allows it).

Comment: Use "_system" not "_blank" to open in Safari using the InAppBrowser plugin.